# .datepicker date selection effects query

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, date

I am working on my personal work website. 
My problem is, in calender "From" date can be picked even before today (not good), moreover if "From" date is selected 5 days from today, in "To" date it still gives me option to select date for before "From" selected date.
while it should only let me select date beyond what I have in "From" date. Moreover can't figure out how to bring hover effect in "end date"(Like even if hover 6th day from now, shouls highlight 5th & sixth day.)

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#from').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths:2
    });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#to').datepicker({
        numberOfMonths:2
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [API DatePicker](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker)
you need to set minDate & maxDate on selection.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#from').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths:2, 
    onSelect: function (date) {
        $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", date);
    }
});

$('#to').datepicker({
    numberOfMonths:2,
    onSelect: function (date) {
                $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date);
            }        
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To adjust the from date and set the minDate try something like the following.

You can find the api documentation here: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#from').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths:2, 
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    });

    $('#to').datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        numberOfMonths:2
    });
});
```